# Searching for a 3d engine. (Mac, cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, macos, 3d-engine

What 3d engines are avaliable for mac to use with cocoa? (xcode)?? A list of all would be great + a recommend

Thank you very much :)

**EDIT:
In OpenGL. There is a 2d engine which uses opengl but i need a 3d engine for physics simulation in OpenGL. *(shoot'em up)***

Comment: Do you have more specific requirements? What kind of engine? For a shoot-'em-up game? For a RTS game? For a (MMO)RPG game? For a puzzle game? For CAD modelling? For physics simulations/visualizations? For... what purpose?

Comment: You need to provide more detail.

Comment: He's asking about the Mac though, not iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galaxy Engine meets all your requirements - Cocoa, 3D and OpenGL - and is free and open source.

http://code.google.com/p/galaxyengine/

EDIT: I read your edit and saw that you need physics as well. Bullet works well with Galaxy Engine, which unfortunately is lacking a physics model of its own: http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

Answer (score -3):

A simple answer for a simple question: [OpenGL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html).